# Changing text size via button

Tags: javascript, html, css

could someone please explain to me, why id of "he" changes the font size, however id "clanky" stays the same.

```
<h1 id="he">Zoznam článkov / Article List</h1>
<main id="clanky"></main> //there are articles plugged in there in different function  

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("he").style.fontSize = "90px";
  document.getElementById("clanky").style.fontSize = "90px";
}
```

I tried just changing the color to see if it works overall and yes, the color does change in both of them. Anyone might have an idea, what is blocking the "clanky" font size to be changed?

Comment: Are you looking to increase the font size of every element or just those two?

Comment: where did you call your function?

Comment: Do you have some css style rule for that element that is using `!important`?

Comment: Kindly post minimal code so that we can help you better.

Comment: @HaldenCollier I am looking to increase the size of every element

Comment: Ok, in that case, I may have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to increase every elements font size you will have to have a root/default set somewhere. This will usually just be in the styling of your `<body>`.

**Example (CSS)**:

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Now that there is a 'default' size, you can go to which ever element you want and use the `rem` and `em` units rather than `px`.

So instead of typing `16px` on every element, you can now do `1em`.

This means that so when you change the root size, every other element that uses `em` or `rem` should be effected.

(**Note**: the button's font size won't change in this snippet. If you would like that to happen you will have to add `font-size: 1em;` in CSS to your `button` tag.)

Read more about `em` and `rem` units [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/comprehensive-guide-when-to-use-em-vs-rem--cms-23984).

```js
document.getElementById('increaseFont').onclick = function () {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]; 
    
    body.style.fontSize = "22px"; // - Whatever you want the font the increase to.
};

document.getElementById('defaultSize').onclick = function () {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]; 
    
    body.style.fontSize = "16px"; // -- THE DEFAULT FONT SIZE IN CSS
};
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>I am a heading!</h1>
<p>I'm just a small paragraph...</p>

<button id="increaseFont" type="button">
    Increase all fonts
</button>

<button id="defaultSize" type="button">
    Default font size
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does.  You didn't include enough, but my guess is that you're changing the div, but there are tags inside the div that the CSS is controlling.

https://jsfiddle.net/24emLxn7

```
<h1 id="he">Zoznam / Article List</h1>
<main id="clanky">blah blah</main>

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction();">push me 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction2();">push me 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the article is plugged there from another place, there are inline font-size in that article that you can not override by setting font-size on parent element. Thats all.

Answer (score -1):

Working fine. Maybe you have some other event on div inside the main tag.

```
<h1 id="he">Zoznam clánkov / Article List<br>Hello</h1>
<main id="clanky"></main> 
<input type='button' value="Change Font Size" onclick='myFunction();'>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("clanky").innerHTML='Hello';
  document.getElementById("he").style.fontSize = "90px";
  document.getElementById("clanky").style.fontSize = "90px"; 
}
```